# headless chrome in docker with python. Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: python, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run this simple script inside a docker container:

```
def hi_chrome():
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
    from splinter import Browser
    vdisplay = Xvfb()
    vdisplay.start()

    print "spawning connector"
    oBrowser = Browser('chrome')
    oBrowser.visit("http://google.co.za")
    assert oBrowser.title == "Google"
    print "yay"
    vdisplay.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hi_chrome()
```

I've gotten the script to run in a virtual environment by doing all the pip and apt-get installs listed in the my docker file and just running the script.  But when I try run it inside a container I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
    hi_chrome()
  File "app.py", line 10, in hi_chrome
    oBrowser = Browser('chrome')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.8.0-34-generic x86_64)
```

I've had similar problems when trying to run my script using other containers on docker-hub. I've tried using chrome instead of chromium and I've tried using some containers I found on docker-hub but I keep finding broken nonesense. This should be simple.

My main suspicion is that it's a versioning thing. But it works in the venv so that doesnt make too much sense. Or docker just needs something fancy to get the chrome webdriver to run.

Can someone please point out my obvious and noobish mistake?

My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev xvfb chromium-browser && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip install chromedriver_installer

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

And requirements.txt:

```
splinter==0.7.5
xvfbwrapper==0.2.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an image that sorta worked and then beat it into submission... Nice thing about this solution is it doesn't need `xvfbwrapper` so it's nice and simple.

App.py

```
def hi_chrome():
    # from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
    from splinter import Browser
    # vdisplay = Xvfb()
    # vdisplay.start()

    print "spawning connector"
    oBrowser = Browser('chrome')
    oBrowser.visit("http://google.co.za")
    assert oBrowser.title == "Google"
    print "yay"

    # vdisplay.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hi_chrome()
```

requirements:

```
 splinter==0.7.5
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM markadams/chromium-xvfb

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python python-pip curl unzip libgconf-2-4

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.26

RUN curl -SLO "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
  && unzip "chromedriver_linux64.zip" -d /usr/local/bin \
  && rm "chromedriver_linux64.zip"

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```